# Как заполнить поля юзер и пароль на обновившейся странице(автотест)?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, автоматизация, uiautomation

Только начинаю разбираться в автотестировании.
Пишу автотест(использую селениум и с#) для этого сайта http://onliner.by

Для начала нужно пройти авторизацию, с помощью xPath нахожу кнопку "Вход"
и кликаю - тут всё в порядке.
Затем страница обновляется, появляются поля для ввода логина и пароля, но адрес страницы при этом остаётся прежним(http://onliner.by).
[Обновлённая страница выглядит так](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/11/06/0023/3336/1543432/32/c6a0219dc3.jpg)
Также скопировал Xpath'ы этих элементов, но этот код не работает:

```
        //this doesn't work
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='auth-container__forms']/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")).SendKeys("user");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='auth-container__forms']/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input")).SendKeys("password");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='auth-container__forms']/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/button")).Click();
```

Как мне найти и заполнить эти элементы?

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сделать проще, например так:

```
var inputs = driver.FindElementsByClassName("auth-box__input");
inputs[0].SendKeys("login");
inputs[1].SendKeys("password");
```

Comment: Вопрос был чуть в другом, у меня не находились элементы, так как я не поставил задержку. А так да, спасибо, более лаконичный способ)